# Finding blank lines in a file with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

My apologies for such a rudimentary question, but I am attempting to count the number of blank lines in a text file with awk. This is NOT a homework assignment. Windows 10. Gawk 4.1.3

```
BEGIN { x=0 } 
/^$/  { x=x+1 } 
END   { print "I found " x " blank lines." }
```

The output is always: I found 0 blank lines.

Thanks.

Comment: Your solution works for me. Do you also consider whitespace-only lines blank?

Comment: gawk 'NF==0{x++} END{ print "I found " x " blank lines." }' file

Comment: Since it works according to eush77, it might just be a line-terminator issue. Maybe try piping through `dos2unix` first.

Comment: `grep -cvP '\S' file` or `awk /^[[:space:]]*$/ {x++}` should work.

Comment: Do you have that script saved in a file which you're executing with `awk -f script input` or are you trying to evoke it from the command line with `awk 'BEGIN{...}' input`? If the former, good, if that latter, do the former instead. @Chet if you remove the OPs BEGIN section, which you should, then you need to use printf `%d` or use `x+0` to avoid getting a null instead of zero output for empty files.

Answer (score 5):

The command should work but you can skip the initialization of `x`. `awk` will do it for you automatically. You can use the `NF` variable for that check, if it is `0` which evaluates to `false` the line is empty. Furthermore I suggest to use `printf`:

```
!NF  {x++}
END  {printf "I found %d blank lines\n", x}
```

Btw, you can simply use `grep`

```
grep -ch '^$' file
```

`-c` outputs only the count of occurrences found, `-h` suppresses the output of the file name.

Use command substitution to interpolate the output into an `echo` statement:

```
echo "I found $(grep -ch '^$' file) blank lines"
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the nice awk solution you've already got, the sed solution would be

```
sed -n '/^$/p' file |wc -l
```

Here `-n` suppresses the normal output, `p` prints the lines the line is blank - (`^$`). `wc -l` counts the total number of lines thus printed.